# Remove list from numpy array and just have array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
s = np.array([3, 1])
s_ = np.array([[3], [1]])

$ s.shape
>>> (2,)

$ s_.shape
>>> (2,1)
```

How can I remove the inner `[]` around each value and just have a one-dimensional array?

Specifically, if I have a `list` of `s_`-like arrays, how can I change all of them to be in the `shape` of `s`? E.g.:

```
$ print(test)
>>> [array([[1], [3]]), array([[12], [5]]), ... etc.]
```

Comment: `s_` is a 2d array.  The shape reflects the nesting of brackets in its definition.  There are various ways of `reshaping` it, all basic `numpy` array manipulation.  `squeeze`, `ravel`, `flatten`, `reshape`, indexing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a 1d array you can use flatten() function.

```
s_ = np.array([[3], [1]])
s_ = s_.flatten()

>>> print (s_)
[3 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [163]: s_ = np.array([[3], [1]])                                                              
In [164]: s_                                                                                     
Out[164]: 
array([[3],
       [1]])
In [165]: s_.shape                                                                               
Out[165]: (2, 1)
```

Lots of ways of turning that into a (2,) shape array:

```
In [166]: s_.ravel()                                                                             
Out[166]: array([3, 1])
In [167]: s_.squeeze()                                                                           
Out[167]: array([3, 1])
In [168]: s_[:,0]                                                                                
Out[168]: array([3, 1])

In [170]: s_.reshape(2)                                                                          
Out[170]: array([3, 1])
In [171]: s_.reshape(-1)                                                                         
Out[171]: array([3, 1])
```

As for working with a list of them, `[s_, s_, s_]`, you could just use a list comprehension to make a new list with each one reshaped by one of the above methods.

Or, if they are all have the same shape, they could be joined into one array.

Join them on a new leading dimension:

```
In [172]: np.array([s_,s_,s_])                                                                   
Out[172]: 
array([[[3],
        [1]],

       [[3],
        [1]],

       [[3],
        [1]]])
In [173]: _.shape                                                                                
Out[173]: (3, 2, 1)     # could reshape to (3,2)
```

Join them on the existing size 1 dimension:

```
In [175]: np.concatenate([s_,s_,s_], axis=1)                                                     
Out[175]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1]])
In [176]: _.shape                                                                                
Out[176]: (2, 3)
```

transpose that:

```
In [177]: np.concatenate([s_,s_,s_], axis=1).T                                                   
Out[177]: 
array([[3, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 1]])
```